QGIS Raster Calculator to fill zero values
I have a DSM in GeoTIFF format which has a section of 0 values (the black area in the pic below).
Ideally, I'd like to use the raster calculator to fill that section of 0 values with values which would 'represent' how it may look if it didn't have a hole in it
Hope that makes sense


Might want to have a look at the tools GRASS r.patch and SAGA Patching in Raster tools in QGIS. If you have access to ArcGIS Pro, there is an Elevation Void Fill function that will also do this.

Your area with missing data is rather large. Maybe you should search for some other DSM/DEM data source, even with worse resolution, and use that for filling the hole. It might give a more realistinc result than interpolation. There is a tool for filling small holes https://gdal.org/en/latest/programs/gdal_sieve.html but I do not think it is suitable for your data.

Yes, filling the data with an alternative source of elevation data is also a perfectly viable solution. Thanks user30184 for bringing that up too. It really depends on what kind of data they can get.

I assume what you are trying to do is recreate the topography of the area of 0 values. We typically call that interpolation (more on this in a moment). I don't think you will be able to easily do this in raster calculator, independent of the software you use, and I'm sorry to say this probably won't be a quick fix. One quick step you can do in the meantime is convert the 0 values to Nodata, which will be required for the interpolation.
I would strongly suggest reading up on spatial interpolation methods such as Kriging, Inverse Distance Weighted (IDW), Natural Neighbour, Spline, etc. Interpolation techniques use existing values in the raster and various spatial and statistical relationships to interpolate new values for areas that have no data. I can't say just from this screenshot what the best interpolator method might be for your data, as things like data density and the size of the area to interpolate all play a role. This is why I suggest reading up on the strengths/weaknesses of spatial interpolation techniques and decide for yourself what solution might be best for your data. Of course, you can try as many as you like and see what gives you satisfactory results. Sometimes, a simpler interpolator like IDW is just fine, other times you gotta bring out the big guns and go through the process of setting up a semivariogram for Kriging.
Once you've figured out what interpolation technique works best for your data needs, there are several GIS packages and softwares you can use to perform the interpolation. ArcGIS Pro, QGIS, WhiteboxTools, and likely several Python or R packages if you prefer a coding route. Sorry I can't offer more straightforward help, but as I said there is probably not a straightforward solution to your question.
